# how to write custom flume-ng source for creating avro file on hdfs sink ?

Tags: flume-ng

I'm trying to write a CustomSource which can create avro files on hdfs sink. But I can't figure it out.

Would like to see some guideline or example.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to get the details:
https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html

But on a high level to create a custom flume source:
1. Change the Flume config. Here you add your source configuration and point it to the MyCustomSource.java
2. Write the Source logic in MyCustomSource.java and copy the jar to flume nodes and restart.